# Powershell download and extract from the registry

Tags: powershell

Can you please help me with this code

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -windowstyle hidden -noexit -command (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('Url',"$env:temp\cat.zip"); Expand-Archive "$env:temp\cat.zip" -DestinationPath "$env:temp\pp" -Force"
```

Add in
HKLM\software\microsoft\windows\currentversoin\run, but nothing I put in seems to work after restart.

Comment: If you have tried to put some simpler command into the registry and it doesn't work then your problem is not with PowerShell and this question is not programming related. Does the command work as expected when you run it from a cmd shell?

Comment: When i put the code in the registry it added successfully but after restarting it doesn't run, But when i open the Powershell and run it with this code (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('Url',"$env:temp\cat.zip"); Expand-Archive "$env:temp\cat.zip" -DestinationPath "$env:temp\pp" -Force" It work

Comment: Have you checked the system logs to see if there's a reason that it isn't running?

Comment: Why would you want to download and unpack a zip file from the web every time a user logs in?

Comment: In the RunOnce, Just one time

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of quotes, and they don't look right. You didn't start your command with a quote, but you ended it with a quote. This should do it:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('Url',""$env:temp\cat.zip""); Expand-Archive ""$env:temp\cat.zip"" -DestinationPath ""$env:temp\pp"" -Force"
```

*Also, I dropped `-NoExit`, but maybe you really do want powershell to stay running.*

Additionally, powershell's executor handles encoded commands and gives you instructions on how to do it: `powershell.exe /?`:

> ## To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
>
> $command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
>
> $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
>
> $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
>
> powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand

You didn't give me the `URL` or I would encode it for you, but this will help save you some headache when passing complex commands into powershell.exe like this. Here's how you might pass in the command from the example via the registry:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -EncodedCommand ZABpAHIAIAAiAGMAOgBcAHAAcgBvAGcAcgBhAG0AIABmAGkAbABlAHMAIgAgAA==
```